# how can I getting tkinter entry widget value in pygubu?

Tags: python-3.x, tkinter, pygubu

I use tkinter in pygubu. I want I get value of Entry_1 widget.
the Entry_1 widget value is blue. and textvariable of Entry_1 is 'text_1'
I read pygubu document. but I don't understand.
who can know me easy please.

and  I Link ask.ui file to use pygubu
http://www.joinsland114.mireene.com/data/ask.ui

```
try:
    import tkinter as tk  # for python 3
except:
    import Tkinter as tk  # for python 2
import pygubu
from tkinter import *

class Application:
    def __init__(self, master):

        #1: Create a builder
        self.builder = builder = pygubu.Builder()

        #2: Load an ui file
        builder.add_from_file('ask.ui')

        #3: Create the widget using a master as parent
        self.mainwindow = builder.get_object('Frame_1', master)

        builder.connect_callbacks(self)


root = tk.Tk()
app = Application(root)

print(app.mainwindow.getvar('text_1'))    
root.mainloop()
```

> Traceback (most recent call last):   File "C:\Python34\pygubu.py", line
>   25, in 
>       print(app.mainwindow.getvar('text_1'))   File "C:\Python34\lib\tkinter__init__.py", line 454, in getvar
>       return self.tk.getvar(name)
>   _tkinter.TclError: can't read "text_1": no such variable

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use pygubu-designer to open your *ask.ui* file, then expand Frame_2 and click on Entry_1. In the section below, under the General tab, you will see the *textvariable* is empty. In this field enter: **entry1_var**.

For Entry_2 enter in the *textvariable* field: **entry2_var** and for Entry_3 enter in the *textvariable* field: **entry3_var**.

To make clicking on the OK button print to the console the 3 variable values of blue, yellow and green, then: Select Button_1 and in its *command* field enter: **button1_callback**.

On the main menubar, click File and Save the *ask.ui* file.

If you now look around through the contents of the *ask.ui* file the following four lines have been added to it...

```
<property name="textvariable">string:entry1_var</property>
<property name="textvariable">string:entry2_var</property>
<property name="textvariable">string:entry3_var</property>
<property name="command">button1_callback</property>
```

The following method is now added to the *ask.py* file:

```
def button1_callback(self):
    "Display the values of the 3 x Entry widget variables"
    print(self.builder.tkvariables['entry1_var'].get())
    print(self.builder.tkvariables['entry2_var'].get())
    print(self.builder.tkvariables['entry3_var'].get())

    # Change Entry_3 from green to red 
    self.builder.tkvariables['entry3_var'].set("red"))
```

Also delete or comment out the line *#print(app.mainwindow.getvar('text_1'))*

Your *ask.py* file should now look like this...

```
try:
    import tkinter as tk  # for python 3
except:
    import Tkinter as tk  # for python 2
import pygubu
from tkinter import *

class Application:
    def __init__(self, master):

        #1: Create a builder
        self.builder = builder = pygubu.Builder()

        #2: Load an ui file
        builder.add_from_file('ask.ui')

        #3: Create the widget using a master as parent
        self.mainwindow = builder.get_object('Frame_1', master)

        builder.connect_callbacks(self)

    def button1_callback(self):
        "Display the values of the 3 x Entry widget variables"
        print(self.builder.tkvariables['entry1_var'].get())
        print(self.builder.tkvariables['entry2_var'].get())
        print(self.builder.tkvariables['entry3_var'].get())

        # Change Entry_3 from green to red 
        self.builder.tkvariables['entry3_var'].set("red")

root = tk.Tk()
app = Application(root)

#print(app.mainwindow.getvar('text_1')) <-- This is commented out   
root.mainloop()
```

Run your python program and click on the OK button. The console will display:

```
$ python3 ask.py
blue
yellow
green
```

The third entry widget will change from displaying *green* to *red*.